# Convert string date to GETDATE() format in SQL server

Tags: sql, sql-server, string, datetime

We have a table employee with columns `LastUpdated (datetime)`, `ExitDate (datetime)` and `ReleaseDate (varchar(50))`.

The date in the table is shown here:

```
+-------------------------+----------------------+
|       LastUpdated       |     ReleaseDate      |
+-------------------------+----------------------+
| 2019-05-24 01:19:21.597 | 4/8/2016 7:00:00 AM  |
| 2019-05-24 02:05:26.130 | 3/20/2007 7:00:00 AM |
| 2019-05-24 01:57:44.810 | 5/14/2007 7:00:00 AM |
| 2019-05-24 01:48:40.483 | 3/16/2010 7:00:00 AM |
| 2019-05-24 01:11:41.290 | 11/8/2018 8:00:00 AM |
+-------------------------+----------------------+
```

Now I want to convert the `ReleaseDate` column values into the `LastUpdated` column format (`yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss`) and update the value to the column `ExitDate`.

The `LastUpdated` column value was inserted using `GETDATE()` in SQL Server.

Can anyone help with this, please?

Comment: Once you get this updated you need to change the datatype of your column and stop storing dates as strings. Choosing the right datatype is **extremely** important. https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/12/bad-habits-to-kick-choosing-the-wrong-data-type

Comment: Dates have no format, they are binary values. You have a serious bug, storing strings instead of dates. Fix the bug. Seriously. Otherwise you won't be able to index or query that field. In the image you posted `5/14/2007` is *greater* than `4/8/2016`.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `update` :

```
update employee
     set ExitDate = convert(datetime, ReleaseDate, 101);
```

However, storing date value into other format not a good practice.

Answer (score 0):

You can parse the string to a date, then convert the date to a string in the desired format.  The string formats supported for datetime conversions are documented [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/cast-and-convert-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15).

So something like:

```
update employee set ReleaseDate = convert(varchar(50), convert(datetime,ReleaseDate, 101), 121);
```

if all the rows are in the same date format.  If the date format varies, you can try:

```
update employee set ReleaseDate = convert(varchar(50), convert(datetime,ReleaseDate), 121);
```

to convert using the your current culture settings and SQL Server's permissive conversion rules.

But you should then alter the column's datatype, if, and when that is possible:

```
alter table employee alter column ReleaseDate datetime
```

or add a check constraint to force the application to make sure no other format is inserted.

```
alter table employee add constraint [ck_EnforceReleaseDateFormat_YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS]
check (ReleaseDate = convert(varchar(50), convert(datetime,ReleaseDate, 121), 121))
```